# What is 'stream' with IBM Watson Speech-to-text?

Tags: node.js, speech-to-text, ibm-watson

I can't find documentation for the methods `stream.on` and `stream.recognizeStream.on`. I've searched the [documentation](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/speech-to-text/index.html) and the [API](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/speech-to-text/api/v1/). My specific question at this moment is about promises, e.g., this doesn't work:

```
stream.on('data', function(transcribedSpeech) {
  console.log(transcribedSpeech);
})
.then(function() {
  console.log("Then...");
  this.transcribedSpeech = transcribedSpeech;
})
.catch(function() {
  console.log("Error");
});
```

The error is `TypeError: stream.on(...).then is not a function`. I'm trying to make an Angularjs service for IBM Watson Speech-to-text. Everything is working, i.e., the messages, transcripts, keywords, etc. from Watson are logging to the console, except that I can't get the data stream from the service to the controller. When I call the service from the controller, the controller sees only the initial values of the parameters (`undefined`), and never sees the values after Watson starts sending the data stream. I was hoping that a promise would fix this but no luck. :-(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not one expert in Speech to text, but I did one example a few months ago using the API Reference and the project by IBM.

As you can see, the following example is used in the API Reference, the `recognizeStream` is used for the instance of Speech to text, and for recognize the speech that you sent, the `createRecognizeStream` [function](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/speech-to-text/api/v1/?node#recognize_audio_websockets) [Node SDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk).

You can use other variable, depends of you, but, you need to instance the speech to text and call the createRecogniseStream for recognize the event of Speech.

The service will transcript your file after setting with utf8 and added the transcript file the text recognized, like the following example:

```
var SpeechToTextV1 = require('watson-developer-cloud/speech-to-text/v1');
var fs = require('fs');

var speech_to_text = new SpeechToTextV1 ({
  username: '{username}',
  password: '{password}'
});

var params = {
  model: 'en-US_BroadbandModel',
  content_type: 'audio/flac',
  'interim_results': true,
  'max_alternatives': 3,
  'word_confidence': false,
  timestamps: false,
  keywords: ['colorado', 'tornado', 'tornadoes'],
  'keywords_threshold': 0.5
};

// Create the stream with the instancie of speech to text and access the function to Recognise the speech.
var recognizeStream = speech_to_text.createRecognizeStream(params);

// Pipe in the audio in the parameter recognizeStream.
fs.createReadStream('audio-file.flac').pipe(recognizeStream);

// Pipe out the transcription to a file.
recognizeStream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('transcription.txt'));

// Get strings instead of buffers from 'data' events.
recognizeStream.setEncoding('utf8');

// Listen for events using the paramter after set utf8 and the transcrit file.
recognizeStream.on('results', function(event) { onEvent('Results:', event); });
recognizeStream.on('data', function(event) { onEvent('Data:', event); });
recognizeStream.on('error', function(event) { onEvent('Error:', event); });
recognizeStream.on('close', function(event) { onEvent('Close:', event); });
recognizeStream.on('speaker_labels', function(event) { onEvent('Speaker_Labels:', event); });

// Displays events on the console.
function onEvent(name, event) {
  console.log(name, JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
};
```

- See the [Official](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/speech-to-text/api/v1/?node#recognize_audio_websockets) reference using Speech to text with Node.js
- [Project](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-to-text-nodejs) by IBM Developers using Speech to text and Node.js